# is it necessary to implement ModelForm in our project to implement a CreateView (CBV) in Django 2.0.2?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-2.0

I am a beginner programming in Django framework and I am learning how to implement a CreateView (a class based view for creating a form based on a model) in my views.py file.

Comment: Please vote an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't the view will automatically create a model form for you, but you have to option of overwriting it.

Let's assume you have `MyModel`, you can do this:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

# views.py

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['something', 'somethingelse']  # these are fields from MyModel
```

If you do not specify the `fields` Django will throw an error.

If you want to customize your form validation in some way, you can do this:

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['something']  # form fields that map to the model

        # ... do some custom stuff

# views.py
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm
```

Notice that we are not specifying the `fields` anymore on `MyView` because if we would it will also throw an error, and the reasons is because the view will fetch the fields from the form.

More information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Code that handles the `form_class`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L74

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a ModelForm, you just need to specify the model in the `model` attribute, e.g. for an `Author` model set `model = Author`.

`CreateView` uses the [ModelFormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin), which uses this `model` attribute to handle the ModelForm:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```

See more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.model